# Recompile a package for debian

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, debian

I want to recompile a Ubuntu package to use it on Debian

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hollywood
```

how can I do that please ? I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You need the original tar-ball for the package, and the "debian" tarball which contains the scripts and patches needed to build the package.  Finding those on Ubuntu's website is really the hard part.

Given those, you could use [dpkg-buildpackage](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html) (on a system comparable to your target, of course), which expects the latter untar'd in the current directory, along with the original tar-ball.

(I build my own packages with a script which stages things into this arrangement; Debian packagers use a different scheme).